# What type of event is control-click in gwt

Tags: gwt, cell, jquery-ui-selectable

What is the event type for the control click in a table cell in a GWT application?  I want to basically change the color of the background when the user does this action.

This part of my code basically just looks like:

```
public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
        Element td = getEventTargetCell(event);

        if (td == null) return;
        Element tr = DOM.getParent(td);

        System.out.println("Event " + Event.getCurrentEvent());
        switch (DOM.eventGetType(event)) {
        case Event.ONMOUSEDOWN: {
            //DOM.setStyleAttribute(td, "backgroundColor", "#ffce00");
            onRowClick(tr);
            break;
        }
        case Event.ONMOUSEUP: {
            //DOM.setStyleAttribute(td, "backgroundColor", "#ffffff");
            break;
        }
        case Event.ONMOUSEOVER: {
            //DOM.setStyleAttribute(td, "backgroundColor", "#ffce00");
            onRowRollover(tr);
            break;
        }
        case Event.ONMOUSEOUT: {
            //DOM.setStyleAttribute(td, "backgroundColor","#ffffff");
            break;
        }
        /*case Event.ONCLICK: {
            DOM.setStyleAttribute(td, "backgroundColor", "#ffce00");
            break;
        }*/
        case Event.ONDBLCLICK: {
            //DOM.setStyleAttribute(td, "backgroundColor", "#ffffff");
            break;
        }
        case Event.KEYEVENTS: {
            //DOM.setStyleAttribute(td, "backgroundColor", "#ffce00");
            break;
        }
        case Event.ONFOCUS: {
            //DOM.setStyleAttribute(td, "backgroundColor", "#ffce00");
            break;
        }
        /*case Event. {
            DOM.setStyleAttribute(td, "backgroundColor", "#ffce00");
            break;
        }*/
        }

    }
```

What do I need to do to capture this event?

Answer (score 2):

The http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/Event.html object passed into onBrowserEvent has methods. Methods such as `boolean getCtrlKey()`.

```
case Event.ONCLICK: {
    if (event.getCtrlKey()) {
        DOM.setStyleAttribute(td, "backgroundColor", "#ffce00");
    }
    break;
}
```

This will work for Windows, not sure about Mac and Linux. On OS X you might check getMetaKey() instead, since Command is normally used where Control is used on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

How about wrapping the contents of the cell in a [`FocusPanel`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FocusPanel.html) and adding the appropriate handler (most likely [`MouseDownHandler`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/MouseDownHandler.html))? (tip: create the handler once and add it to all the related cells)
You can also add key handlers, etc. to `FocusPanel` so you won't need to dabble in native browser events (which could lead to some trouble, browser-specific code, etc.), let GWT do that for you :)